# Macro with attributes in rust

Tags: rust

I'm working with the rust WMI crate, which means I need to add something like this into a lot of structs:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
#[serde(rename = "Win32_PhysicalMemory")]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
```

Is there a way to create a macro that can apply these attributes? So I can just use

```rust
#[foo("Win32_OperatingSystem")]
```

and have it apply

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
#[serde(rename = "Win32_OperatingSystem")]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
```

I tried using the following to make a procedural macro

```rust
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn dumb_attributes(attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    #![derive(Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
    #![serde(rename = <something>)]
    #![serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
    item
}
```

but I'm not sure how to pass the argument from `attr` into the inside attributes.

Comment: Yes. Although I'm not sure this is a good idea.

Comment: Why not? Would you suggest just typing it out manually?

Comment: Because creating a macro for that seems like an overkill for me. But this up to your opinion.

Comment: If I have, say, 20 such structs, then I think it's worth it. If you know how to do it, I would appreciate you making an answer :)

Comment: You asked "is there a way". So yes :) If you're struggling with it, you need to provide more context - what you tried, where you failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work. You're applying the attributes to the proc macro itself.

Proc macro should manipulate the `TokenStream` they receive and add/remove the tokens from there. The simplest way to do that is using the [`quote`](https://docs.rs/quote) crate:

```rust
use quote::quote;

#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn dumb_attributes(attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let item = proc_macro2::TokenStream::from(item);
    quote! {
        #[derive(Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
        #[serde(rename = <something>)]
        #[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
        // The `#` tells `quote!` to interpolate `item`'s contents here,
        // and not insert the literla `item`.
        #item
    }
    .into()
}
```

If you need to pass arguments, you need to parse `attr`. Since your argument is only one string, this is easy. You don't even need to perform validation, just interpolate `attr` into `#[serde(rename)]`:

```rust
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn dumb_attributes(attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let attr = proc_macro2::TokenStream::from(attr);
    let item = proc_macro2::TokenStream::from(item);
    quote! {
        #[derive(Deserialize, Clone, Debug)]
        #[serde(rename = #attr)]
        #[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
        #item
    }
    .into()
}
```

Comment: Do I use `proc_macro` or `proc_macro2` for this?

Comment: `proc_macro` has the real `TokenStream` type. `proc_macro2` is a crate to help testing proc macros, and it has its own `TokenStream`. A procedural macro takes `proc_macro::TokenStream` and produces the same type, but `quote` gives you a `proc_macro2::TokenStream` (this is the reason for the `into()`).

Comment: I get the error "the trait bound `proc_macro::TokenStream: quote::ToTokens` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `quote::ToTokens`". What is the best way to show my full file? Should I edit my question?